# permission denied for view my_view in postgres_fdw

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-fdw

I have 2 databases db1 & db2,
I created postgres_fdw into db1 & db 2 with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
```

I configured server and user mapping into db2 :

```
CREATE SERVER remote_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host 
'my_host', port '5432', dbname 'db1');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER remote_server OPTIONS (user 'my_user', 
password 'my_pass');
```

and Import to my db2 :

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public LIMIT TO (my_view) FROM SERVER remote_server 
INTO public;
```

All configuration is correct and my view imported succesfully to foreign table but i get :

**ERROR:  permission denied for view my_view*

by the way i tried :

```
GRANT SELECT ON my_view TO postgres;
```

but i still get same error
how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection to `db1` is made with the user you specify in the user mapping, which is `my_user`. So you need to grant that privilege to that user:

```
GRANT SELECT ON my_view TO my_user;
```

Comment: as i mention i used that before but i still have error, how can i fix?

Comment: No, you didn't mention that at all. You mentioned that you granted the privilege to user `postgres`, which is different.

Comment: Thanks alot my problem fixed!